# failed to readLines and get error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, readlines

Want to output a list of directories with ReadLines but returned an error of:
"Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/features/002': Permission denied".
I have checked file.exists(), setwd, also shut down my antivirus, and change to the administrator as some similar post suggests, still no.

```
setwd("C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/features")
File_directory="C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/features"
Pathway=list.files(File_directory, full.names = T)
Ids_no = length(Pathway)
for (i in 1:ids_no){
Data_path = readLines(Pathway[i])
}
```

I tested readLines separately for a txt file, it worked fine. Also if I changed to readline, it return directories one by one. So what can do to resolve the problem with readLines?

```
for (i in 1:ids_no){
Data_path = readline(Pathway[i])
}
```

In the end, I used paste0 to replace the readLines to direct to my subject files.

```
Data_path = paste0(Pathway[i], "/feature.txt", sep = "")
```

Comment: You use `Pathway` to define your file list and then `pathway` in your call to `readLines`.  Assuming the files exist and you have read access, that's probably the issue.  If not, use `file.access()` to test for existence, readability etc before reading.

Comment: it was a typo and I changed it in the post. If file.access() returns 0. what should I do?